Implementing Image Slider applies animation only on the first image
I want to implement image slider with nextjs and tailwind. I have array of images, and I display each image with the following component:
export default function MyImage({ url }) {

  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const onLoadCallback = () => {
    setIsReady(true);
  };

  return (
      <div data-aos="flip-left">
        <Image
            src={url}
            alt={"need to edit this"}
            width={230}
            height={330}
            onLoadingComplete={onLoadCallback}
            className={`max-w-full mx-auto md:max-w-none h-auto rounded-xl transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out cursor-pointer transition duration-1000 ${
              isReady ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'
            }`}
          />
        </div>
      );
}

Then, I call it in the parent component (my slider) like this:
export default function Gallery() {
  const basePath = '/home' 
  const  items  = bootstrap.bootstrap;
  const totalNumber = items.length;
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex) => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };

  const goBack = () => {
    const previous = (index-1+totalNumber)%totalNumber;
    setIndex(previous);
  }

  const goNext = () => {
    const next = (index+1)%totalNumber;
    setIndex(next);
  }

  return (
        <div className="grid grid-rows-1 grid-flow-col gap-4">
          <button type="button" onClick={goBack} class="">
            //my left button
          </button>
          <div data-aos="flip-left">
            <MyImage url={`${basePath}/${items[index].imageUrl}`} />
          </div>
          <button type="button" onClick={goNext} class="">
            //my right button
          </button>
        </div>
      );
}

The gallery component works fine - next and previous button load the images in the way they are supposed to.
My problem is that the animation data-aos="flip-left" applies only on the first image. I want it to apply for every image in the array of images.
How do I do that?
